# The name of an honest woman

Tags: proverbs

Could someone clarify the meaning of the following proverb?

> The name of an honest woman is mickle worth.

(the entry in the *Oxford Dictionary of English Proverbs* is not very helpful)

Answer (score 5):

"It's extremely valuable to have a reputation as an honest woman."

[**Name**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/name?s=t) - reputation (sense 3)
[**Mickle**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mickle?s=t) - great, large, much
[**Worth**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/worth?s=t) - importance or value (sense 5 or 6)

Comment: Okay for [1721](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BEgOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA334&dq=%22honest+woman%22+%22mickle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pTH2ULS_POSo0AXhx4CYDA&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22honest%20woman%22%20%22mickle%22&f=false), but you probably wouldn't want to quote this particular "proverb" today. Most people just know [many a mickle makes a muckle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/many_a_mickle_makes_a_muckle), from which they'll erroneously assume *mickle = little bit*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I can safely say that most American people have never heard the proverb you quote. Maybe that's a UK thing. I had no idea what "mickle" meant until reading this post.

Comment: @Jay Not even in *“mickle mirth”*?  *Mickle* is a fine word of long standing in the English language: “Ther was mekyl melody at that chyldes berthe, / Alle tho wern in hevene blys thei made mekyl merthe.” > “There was mickle melody at that Child's birth, /
 All that were in heaven's bliss, they made mickle mirth.”

Comment: @tchrist your knowledge of Middle English is benefiting your knowledge more than it would some others. *Mickle* is found in Scots and Ulster-Scots, and hence not unheard of where those dialects had an influence (Parts of Scotland, North England, and Ulster), but largely died out elsewhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's ironic since *muckle* is a variant of *mickle*. The phrase was originally "many a pickle makes a mickle/muckle". Curious transformation, since taken straight the form you give is tautologous to the point of meaningless, but I see it is indeed attested.

Comment: @Jon: Per [this chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+a+mickle+makes%2Cmany+a+pickle+makes%2Cmany+a+little+makes&year_start=1770&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), it's probably fair to say the "original" was in fact *little*. I'd guess *pickle* is just a desperate attempt to introduce a credible alliteration to compete with etymologically indefensible version which is now the standard for most people - many of whom are perfectly well aware of the fact that it's effectively nonsense.

Comment: @tchrist No, I have never heard the phrase "mickle mirth" before your post. As I say, this is not a word commonly heard in America. And when I say "commonly", I mean "ever".

Comment: @Jay I’ve a sister-in-law of somewhat dour disposition who goes by the name of Micky. “Mickle mirth” has come to be an ironic description of her demeanor.